# Where is the missing postgres-plpython-12 for Ubuntu 20.04, required for psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, plpython

There is no available package for postgres-plpython-12

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql-plpython

The psycopg2 library does not work with plpython3 (or does it)?

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
```

So how does anyone get psycopg2 working on Ubuntu >= 20.04 ?

The `libpq*` libraries are installed.

```
libpq-dev is already the newest version (13.4-1.pgdg18.04+1).
libpq5 is already the newest version (13.4-1.pgdg18.04+1).
```

Maybe everything must be on postgres-13?  Since there seems to be no explicit candidates for `libpq*` version 12.x

The error above is generated by pytest-postgresql from

```py
postgresql = <connection object at 0x7fa79feaf548; dsn: 'user=postgres password=xxx dbname=app_test host=127.0.0.1 port=15988 options=''', closed: 0>

    @pytest.fixture
    def postgresql_config(postgresql) -> Dict:
        # https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql#how-to-use
        # https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql#configuration
        # see pytest.ini for configuration options
    
        # assert isinstance(postgresql, connection)
        dsn = postgresql.get_dsn_parameters()
        passwd_data = Path(dsn["passfile"]).read_text().strip()
        passwd = passwd_data.split(":")[-1]
        dsn_path = f"{dsn['user']}:{passwd}@{dsn['host']}:{dsn['port']}"
        db_url = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{dsn_path}/{dsn['dbname']}"
        admin_config = {
            "timeout": 10,
            "host": dsn["host"],
            "port": dsn["port"],
            "dbname": dsn["dbname"],
            "username": dsn["user"],
            "password": passwd,
            "url": db_url,
        }
    
        # - init the test-db using the postgres admin user
        # - for some tips on idempotent DDL, see:
        #   https://www.depesz.com/2008/06/18/conditional-ddl/
    
        cursor = postgresql.cursor()
        for statement in sqlparse.split(_setup_sql):
            if statement:
>               cursor.execute(statement)
E               psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
```

Comment: I would not expect psycopg2 to depend on either of those.  What are you doing to generate that error?

Comment: `plpython(3)u` does not use `psycopg2`.  In any case Ubuntu does not include `Python 2 ` by default.  What you are looking for is: `sudo apt install postgresql-plpython3-12` which will install `plpython3u` the Python 3 version of the Python procedural language.

Comment: Psycopg has no connection with PL/Python. One is a client interface, the other a server programming language. All that Psycopg needs is the PostgreSQL client shared library libpq.

Comment: When pypython3 is installed, psycopg2 raises an error that `$libdir/plpythonu` is not available (which is an alias for plpython2u anyway).  This is for a legacy python 3.6 project that was working with postgres-11, postgis, and plpythonu on Ubuntu 18.04 but it seems like it is not possible to get it working on Ubuntu 20.04 with postgres-12 and friends.

Comment: Ah, the `_setup_sql` still contained a `CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;` that needed to be updated to `plpython3u`.  Should have `git grep 'plpython'` to find them all.